# Jackson strange XML Deserializing

Tags: java, xml, jackson, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize in POJO with jackson xml that strange (malformed ?) xml :

```
<module id="1">
    <field id="1">
      <title>test</title>
      <value>test value</value>
    </field>
    <field id="6">
      <title>test2</title>
      <value>first value</value>
      <value checked="false">second value</value>
    </field>
</module>
```

Here is the model I have used so far :

```
public class Field{

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String id;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "title")
    private String title;

    @JsonDeserialize(as=Value.class)
    private Value value;
}


public class Value{

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String checked;

    @JacksonXmlText(value = true)
    private String value;
}
```

So far I am able to read nearly everything except the "value" tag.
I can have it if there is only one "value" tag, but once there is multiple "value" tag I only get the last one ! Of course I need to get everything.

I also tried to put an array of Value class but that crashes jackson it seems.

Any help would be greatly appreciated ^^
Thank you !

Comment: Is the following a cut and paste error, or a real typo: `<title>test</titre>` ?

Comment: paste error, updating the question ! and thanks for pointing the error ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make value as a list or array and use `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper` annotation. Try this.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlText;

@JacksonXmlRootElement
class Module {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String id;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "field")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)
    List<Field> field;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List<Field> getField() {
        return field;
    }
    public void setField(List<Field> field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Module [id=" + id + ", " + field + "]";
    }
}

class Field {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String id;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "title")
    private String title;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "value")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)
    private List<Value> value;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public List<Value> getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(List<Value> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Field [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", value=" + value
                + "]";
    }
}

class Value{

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String checked;

    @JacksonXmlText(value = true)
    private String value;

    public String getChecked() {
        return checked;
    }
    public void setChecked(String checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Value [checked=" + checked + ", " + value + "]";
    }
}

public class JacksonXmlParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        Module obj = xmlMapper.readValue(new File("module.xml"), Module.class);
        System.out.println(obj);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your class Field is flawed, it should contain a list of Value instead of a single one, replace

```
private Value value;
```

with

```
private List<Value> values;
```

and in your xml you hava a tag named `<title>..</title>` and in Field there is a mismatch with `titre`

juste replace

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "titre")
```

with

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "title")
```

Comment: When I set it to List<Value> values, I get the following exception : com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to narrow type [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class com.example.jacksontest.model.Value]] with concrete-type annotation (value com.example.jacksontest.model.Value), method 'valeurs': Class com.example.jacksontest.model.Value is not assignable to java.util.List

Comment: For the replace, this is just a typo in my question. Thank you !

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to use jackson (it serialize to json but this should be the same) : http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-Serialization-list.jsp

Comment: shouldn't u change `@JsonDeserialize(as=Value.class)` to `@JsonDeserialize(as=List<Value.class>)`?

Comment: @Jib'z I have already tried to use JsonCreator, but since it is in xml, it seems to not work the same  with the specific xml annotations or at least I haven't found how to use it yet :-(

Comment: @nafas This do not compile unfortunately

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use Jackson ? Because xstream, I think, handles XML in a easier way and Jackson is better for Json.